# DataTrigger's EnterAction/ExitAction animations conflict

Tags: wpf, xaml

Originally I had a DataTrigger, that set visibility to collapsed:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Confidence}" Value="0">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I want smooth FadeOut/FadeIn animations instead setting visibility, where FadeOut is slower than FadeIn animation, so I've used EnterActions and ExitAction of DataTrigger:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutStoryboard" Duration="0:0:1">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard  x:Key="FadeInStoryboard" Duration="0:0:0.2">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
</Storyboard>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Confidence}" Value="0">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" />
     </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
     <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" />
      </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

**The problem is, that sometimes the UIElement stays semitransparent and no animations are running**

The confidence property is changing in realtime, but when the UIElement is semitransparent the value is constantly higher than 0.

I have also tried stopping the storyboards, but that havnen't solved the problem.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Confidence}" Value="0">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginFadeIn" />
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginFadeout" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeOutStoryboard}" />
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginFadeout" />
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginFadeIn" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInStoryboard}" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to set Duration on Animation explicitely and not just on Storyboard:

It seems like animations does not inherit duration from storyboard and there is some default duration 1s.

When duration is set on storyboard and its smaller than animations the animation are clipped.

Answer (score 0):

It appears a problem with decimal values in duration. You can choose from various easing functions to simulate faster animation effect in same duration like below : 
[MSDN reference for Easing Modes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.easingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Storyboard  x:Key="FadeInStoryboard" Duration="0:0:1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase Amplitude='1' EasingMode='EaseIn' />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
```